# \ref{label>} yields the chapter

Tags: tables, cross-referencing

When I refer to a table in text, the `\ref{<labeloftable>}` statement produces the chapter number in which the table resides, instead of the number of the table.

Any help would be welcomed!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. If the label statement of the table is defined before the caption statement, the `\ref` statement in text produces the chapter in which the table resides.

Switch places and it works a charm!

Comment: when we first started working on the uk tex faq, this question was one of the ones that "will stop appearing"...   such high hopes: it's turned up with monotonous regularity ever since!